# does redirecting a page divides a page's reputation for SEO

Tags: javascript, php, seo, redirect

I have a form and I want to submit it to a `url` `'/finalResult-{filteredSlug}'`. But as the slug part is based on user input, I want to process this slug first and then finally go to `'/finalResult-{filteredSlug}'`.

So, to do that, what I can think of is, that I first submit it to a url `'/finalResult-{slug}'`, edit the form input and then I redirect to my desired page, `'/finalResult-{filteredSlug}'`.

I want to do this because I want my URL to be SEO friendly(not just some abstract user input). So, from the perspective of SEO, will this divide the reputation of my desired page `'/finalResult-{filteredSlug}'` page between `'/finalResult-{slug}'` and `'/finalResult-{filteredSlug}'`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: amm, stackoverflow doesn't allow questions of SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way. I used '**`onsubmit`**' attribute of form to call a function. In that function, I filtered the input and then changed the '`action`' attribute(in the function itself) using the filtered input.